# How to implement Oracle Streams in different Schema name?

Tags: database, schema, oracle11gr2, oracle-streams

I want to implement oracle streams in different schema name..for example
schema1.jobs to schema2.jobs
because most of people give example in same schema..like scott.emp to scott.emp :(

anybody have any advice and thread ?

thank you so much :)

Comment: you want to rename your schema?

Comment: I dont think so dude because Im not use same database..in my case, I have 2 database instance..and orcl(schema1) - target(schema2)
any idea?
Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

you must configure the apply process. To do this you should add rules to the rule set. With this configuration, the apply process dequeues the LCR (Logical Change Record) events and applies all changes to the destination schema. In order to do this, execute the following in the destination DB as strmadmin user:

```
SQL> begin
  dbms_streams_adm.add_schema_rules (
  schema_name => 'XXX',
  streams_type => 'apply',
  streams_name => 'apply_strm',
  queue_name => 'capture_Downstream',
  include_dml => true,
  include_ddl => true,
  source_database => 'SOURCE_GLOBAL_NAME');  
end;
/
```

You should adjust the parameters based on your case. See the https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96612/d_strm_2.htm it is for 9.2